# SonarQube wrapper stopped on Windows

Tags: android, windows, kotlin, sonarqube

I want to analyze my Kotlin code with SonarQube except that I have a problem running the server.
During the installation everything worked, but since I stopped the server it is impossible for me to restart it.

When I run the StartSonar file I get this in the console:

```
C:\sonarqube-7.8\bin\windows-x86-64> .\StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:34 WARN  app[][o.s.application.App] SonarQube will require Java 11+ starting on next version
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonarqube-7.8\temp
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:34 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [C:\sonarqube-7.8\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-7.8\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=C:\sonarqube-7.8\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=C:\sonarqube-7.8\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:35 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:35 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:35 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:48 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='web', ipcIndex=2, logFilenamePrefix=web]] from [C:\sonarqube-7.8]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\jre\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonarqube-7.8\temp -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/common/*;C:\sonarqube-7.8\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\sonarqube-7.8\temp\sq-process8492662459842448974properties
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
jvm 1    | 2019.07.01 09:05:53 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

In the wrapper.conf file, I modified the line :

```
wrapper.java.command=java
```

to

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java
```

But nothing changed

With the Git command line, I executed the command

```
netstat -ntlp | grep 9000
```

but no process appears

Comment: Have you checked the files in the logs directory for any additional information?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So apparently it was caused by a double version of the plugin, the official one and the non-official one
I just removed the old one and it works perfectly now !
Hope it will help

Here is the lines of the log files :

```
2019.07.01 08:59:28 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed: Found two versions of the plugin SonarKotlin [kotlin] in the directory extensions/plugins. Please remove one of sonar-kotlin-plugin-1.5.0.315.jar or sonar-kotlin-0.5.2.jar.
2019.07.01 08:59:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database stopped
2019.07.01 08:59:28 INFO  web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2019.07.01 08:59:28 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Hard stopping process
2019.07.01 09:00:48 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2019.07.01 09:00:49 ERROR web[][o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] Fail to start web server
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:427)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:65)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:52)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:97)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:81)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:99)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
2019.07.01 09:00:49 WARN  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start web
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:69)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.start(WebServer.java:52)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:97)
    at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:81)
    at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:99)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:427)
    at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.start(EmbeddedTomcat.java:65)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8000]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

Comment: How did they get there, which one did you remove, where did you remove it from?